# How do I create a customized, live CenOS 7 ISO?

Tags: centos, live-cd

I need to create a bootable, live, desktop ISO.

This will be a utility disk, a bootable ISO image created for the sole purpose of allowing the user to run a script which will resize an existing local disk volume. This ISO **will not** be used to install anything.

I *don't* want *anything* to run unattended. 
I *don't* want to edit the kickstart file unless there's no other option. 
 
I *do not* want to mount existing volumes on the local hard drive.

I have a script for the volume resizing, and I need that script to be present (and executable) in the desktop directory of the **live** filesystem.

I have tried using livecd-tools on Fedora but can't see whether there's an option to add a file to the iso build.

I tried using livecd-creator with a few lines of added syntax:

```
touch /home/liveuser/Desktop/resize.sh
cat > /home/liveuser/Desktop/resize.sh <<EOF
lvchange -a y
ROOTVOL=/dev/mapper/vg_blago-lv_root
mkdir /tmp/lvroot
mount -t ext4 -o ro $ROOTVOL /tmp/lvroot
usedROOT=$(df -h $ROOTVOL |  tail -1 | awk '{print $2}' | awk '{printf("%d\n",$1 + 1)}')
umount /tmp/rootvol
/sbin/lvresize --resizefs --size $usedROOT\g  $ROOTVOL
e2fsck $ROOTVOL
sleep 1
# reduce home volume
HOMEVOL=/dev/mapper/vg_blago-lv_home
mkdir /tmp/lvhome
mount -t ext4 -o ro $HOMEVOL /tmp/lvhome
usedROOT=$(df -h $HOMEVOL |  tail -1 | awk '{print $2}' | awk '{printf("%d\n",$1 + 1)}')
umount /tmp/lvhome
e2fsck $HOMEVOL 
EOF
```

chmod: cannot access '/home/liveuser/Desktop/resize.sh': No such file or directory
chown: invalid user: 'liveuser:liveuser'
/tmp/ks-script-pek0yli8: line 54: restorecon: command not found
ignoring %post failure (code 127)
/ 100.0%

Comment: Also, this system will not have network access while booted to my ISO.

Comment: What partition are you trying to resize? Is it a partition or a logical volume. Unless you are trying to decrease the size of the root partition/lv, you don't need to do it from a Live USB. You can just put it on any USB drive and run it from there.

Comment: Not allowed to use USB drives.

Comment: Then use the optical media.